# splitting tostring output into string

Tags: java

This is my figure class tostring method (super class)

```
public String toString() {
    return "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", color=" + color ;
}
```

This is Rectangular class tostring method (extended figure class)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Rectangle [ "+  super.toString()   + ", width=" + width + ", length=" + length+  "]\n";
}
```

I want to take only the values for x, y, color, width,and length by splitting this tostring method to draw a rectangle again.

My whole program has to draw rectangle by clicking 2 points. when I click exit button it will save the rectangle object in a text file. when I run it again, it has to pop up the previous shape that I drew. I need the previous points to draw rectangle again by using those points.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a string of format "Rectangle [..." back to values ? If you are then the code in your question is useless and an example of the string format would be much more relevant.

Comment: yes, I want the values of x, y, length, and width to draw back my rectangle through rectangle class

Comment: then edit your question. Get rid of that code we don't need to see. Add an example of the expected input format and the expected outputs.

Comment: expected input is something like this
 [Rectangle [ x=165, y=146, color=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0], width=83, length=79] I need to save those number values seperately.

Comment: edit the question dont put it in comments.

Comment: Why? If you have the `Rectangular` object to call `toString()` on, you have all the values you need. Why try to parse the `toString()` output? If you're trying to serialize and deserialize the object, there are much better ways that this.

Comment: I saved bunch of rectangle objects in a linked list to save in a text file. So, in the text file, all the drown rectangle objects in a list. when I run the program again rectangle shape has to be a rectangle as before. Is there any way to draw back my rectangle in GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `toString();` methods as follows:

figure class tostring method (super class)

```
public String toString() {
    return "x-"+ x + "-y-" + y + "-color-" +color ;
}
```

This is Rectangular class tostring method (extended figure class)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString()+"-width-" + width + "-length-"+length+ ";
}
```

then split by using regex `"-"`

```
String [] splittedString = rectangleObject.toString().split("-");
```

Then assign values from array, like

```
String x = splittedString[1];
String y = splittedString[3];
String color = splittedString[5];
String width = splittedString[7];
String length = splittedString[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the toString() from the Rectangle class, your Figure class must be a subclass of Rectangle. Not a super class like you have it. use this:

```
public class Figure extends Rectangle { /* Other code here */ }
```

Then, you need to use the values from the Rectangle subclass in your toString() method. Since the Rectangle class does not have a getColor() method, you need to create it in your own Figure class. It should look like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

/* this.getX(): returns the X values stored in the subclass Rectangle
   this.getY(): returns the Y values stored in the subclass Rectangle
   getColor(): returns the color stored in the figure class. This is the
               method that will be defined by you.
*/

     return "x=" + this.getX() + ", y=" + this.getY() + ", color=" + getColor();

}
```